# Check a message on a certain port

Tags: networking

I have written an integration test in c++ which sends a message (a simple text) to a client using gRPC.
I have specified localhost as a client and used certain port, e.g., 8000.
How can I check on localhost (windows 10) to see if the message has really arrived?
The integration test passes and I want to know whether the result is correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a network sniffer like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org) to capture the network traffic, start Wireshark (or any other tool), set it to capture on the loopback network interface, run your test and filter for the port you are using. you will see if the messages arrive.

Comment: But when I run a test it sends a message and completes. So, will I be able to check later (after filtering) if a message arrives or it might be possible that the message arrived and disappeared before I could even look at it?

Comment: @DavidHovsepyan Yes, you will be able to check later, Wireshark keeps all the traffic after you stop the recording so you can start it before you run your test and stop it after the test completes. all the messages will stay for you to filter even when you are not recording anymore.